# Drupal homepage showing the node/ in search results

Tags: search, indexing, drupal, drupal-8

I have launched a site built in Drupal 8. When building the site the node/2 was assigned as the home page.

Now when I search for the site in Google I see in the results the node in the URL:

e.g. www.domain.com/node/2

I've never seen this before. Is there a way to not get /node/2 indexed?

Answer (score 0):

you can use drupal's pathauto module [https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto]

where you can set your url by using token also.